# Can't find Karliah in Ragged Flagon?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

After I completed "Hard Answers", Karliah said to meet her at the Ragged Flagon in Riften but it didn't give me the quest. I went to the Ragged Flagon but she's not here. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

One of a few things should work:

1. Save your game, exit Skyrim totally, restart it, load game, etc., she may be there.
2. Just wait -- NPCs apparently have lives (one of many things that always fascinated me about that game) so sometimes they go off doing other things, and you just have to wait for them. This includes travel time.
3. Work on another quest, something that takes you to another zone, relatively far away from Riften (so it unloads), that may trigger her to be finished with her "mission" for the next time you return.

One of those things has always worked for me in those cases, and it happened far more often than I would have expected.